# Checking for two cookies in an htaccess file, with an AND-statement

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a little trouble configuring my htaccess-file, and i can't seem to find the right solution.
My project contains a folder with images (root/images), that i have protected with a htaccess file. The file checks for a certain cookie (e.g. cookie_root) and redirects the user if the value doesn't match the correct value (e.g. 12345).

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !cookie_root=12345
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.google.com [R,L]
```

My project also contains a subproject (root/subproject) with the same logic. It has it's own cookie (cookie_sub).

I would also like to access the root/images from within the subproject, so i would like to configure my htaccess file like the following : allow access if cookie_root is correct OR if cookie_sub is correct.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance

Comment: Add a second RewriteCond that does the same check for the other cookie? Multiple RC are joined by an implicit AND by default, but since you are working with negated conditions here, that should be fine.

Comment: _“allow access if cookie_root is correct OR if cookie_sub is correct”_ - that is phrasing it the other way around, you are not explicitly allowing access to anything here, but you are “disallowing” it for specific conditions by redirecting elsewhere. So NOT cookie 1 AND NOT cookie 2 -> redirect